# How to write AWS Glue df column data into separate html files

Tags: python-3.x, aws-glue

I have a glue DynamicFrame and I want to create separate html files from a column data. Suppose there are 100 records then 100 html files should be created in s3.

How to achieve above?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not write to HTML files with Glue.

Comment: Can call a lambda and write HTML files? If yes, then how to invoke lambda for each column value?

Comment: Why do you need HTML?

Comment: That is the requirement.